¿Cómo puedo registrar un dato en una relación uno a muchos en .NET 8?
este es mi primer post acá en la página.
Recientemente empecé a incursionar en la programación en C# usando EntityFramework, Estoy intentando hacer una relación uno a muchos, estos son mis modelos
namespace Models
{
    public class Book
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public required int AuthorId { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("AuthorId")]
        public Author? Author { get; set; }
    }
}

namespace Models
{
    public class Author
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public List<Book> Books { get; set; } = new List<Book>();
    }
}

Como ven tengo los modelos Author y Book. El problema que tengo es que al crear el controlador y hacer las migraciones, al intentar insertar un nuevo author no me lo permite y por el contrario me arroja un error 400, he intentado hacer que la propiedad Book dentro del modelo Author admita valores nulos pero eso no me ha resuelto el problema.
Este es el controlador que estoy realizando.
namespace RelationsTestAPI.Controllers
    {
        [Route("api/[controller]")]
        [ApiController]
        public class AuthorsController : ControllerBase
        {
            private readonly RelationsContext _context;
            public AuthorsController(RelationsContext context)
            {
                _context = context;
            }
    
            [HttpPost("create")]
            public async Task<IActionResult> Create(Author author)
            {
                if (author == null) return NotFound();
                await _context.Authors.AddAsync(author);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                return CreatedAtAction("Post", author.Id, author);
            }
        }
    }

Adjunto una imagen del error que me arroja.

Espero que puedan ayudarme y de antemano gracias.

Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera medalla! No.. no dejes imagenes.. como se supone que alguien te corrija el codigo, editando las imagenes??? tu codigo y tus errores, todo, siempre como texto ;)

@gbianchi ok muchas gracias, ya corregiré eso.

La anotacion de la foreign key no va antes de la propiedad?

@gbianchi aun quitando la anotacion de la foreign key o cambiando la propiedad book para admitir valores nulos, me arroja un error como si no pudiera crear un nuevo author, pese a que la foreign key está en el modelo books.

Es un problema del Swagger al generar el código de pruebas.
Seguramente tú estás enviando esto:
{
  "id": 0,
  "name": "string",
  "books": [
    {
      "id": 0,
      "title": "string",
      "description": "string",
      "authorId": 0,
      "author": "string"
    }
  ]
}

Notar el último campo author, lo pone como string, cuando el campo es del tipo Object. Simplemente debes quitarlo y envíar
{
  "id": 0,
  "name": "string",
  "books": [
    {
      "id": 0,
      "title": "string",
      "description": "string",
      "authorId": 0
    }
  ]
}


Por otro lado, no tiene mucho sentido tener que enviar la Id del autor (que aún no existe) dentro de book. Por lo que tus clases podrías quedar de esta manera:
public class Book
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public Author? Author { get; set; }
}

public class Author
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Book> Books { get; set; } = new List<Book>();
}

Y el JSON que envías es:
{
  "name": "string",
  "books": [
    {
      "title": "string",
      "description": "string"
    }
  ]
}


Hola @Yussef, intenté hacer lo que mencionaste pero sigo teniendo errores, ahora me devuelve este error cuando borro el campo author y envío la petición System.InvalidOperationException: No route matches the supplied values. El número del error es 500.

Ya logré solucionar el problema, resulta que también tenía un problema en el controlador tuve que hacer un cambio en el return del método.
Este es el codigo antes de modificarlo
public async Task<IActionResult> Create(Author author)
{
    if (author == null) return BadRequest();
    await _context.AddAsync(author);
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
    return CreatedAtAction("Post", author.Id, author);
}

Y así quedó despues de la modificación
public async Task<IActionResult> Create(Author author)
{
    if (author == null) return BadRequest();
    await _context.AddAsync(author);
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
    return CreatedAtAction("Create", author.Id, author);
}

